# fwrite(), writing my input and some garbage on my file

Tags: c

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[50];
    char phone[11];
}contato;

int main(){
    contato c;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("lista_contato.txt", "w");

    printf("Nome: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(c.name, 50, stdin);
    printf("Telefone: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(c.phone, 11, stdin);

    fwrite(&c, 1, sizeof(contato), fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

My Input for name: "Name Surname"

My Input for Phone: "1234"

My Output on file: "Name Surname
    ¿@ °@ Vw        (   x
 ¸þa Phone
     "

Whats Happening With this code, and how i can solve it?

Comment: Sidenote: Never `fflush(stdin);`. Use flushing only for output streams.

Comment: You are not checking if your I/O operations fail.

Comment: Is your intent to create text or binary file? It affects how nul characters should be handled. Currently you are opening file in text mode, and then treating it as binary file, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: ^ Mentioned in my answer,

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  the function: `fflush()` is only for output streams. Per the C standard, that statement is undefined behavior. (regardless of what visual studio allows)  Suggest using something like: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`

Comment: regarding: `fgets(c.name, 50, stdin);`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the size of the array `name[]` could (during debugging, etc) change, so a better statement would be: `if( !fgets(c.name, sizeof( c.name), stdin)) { perror( "fgets failed" ); }`  so the enclosed text and the text of the reason the system thinks the operation failed are output to `stderr`.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fwrite()`, always check that returned value is equal to the 3rd parameter, otherwise the operation has failed.  Also, in the current scenario, better to use: `fprintf()` rather than `fwrite()`

Comment: regarding: `fgets(c.name, 50, stdin);`   this will NOT clear the rest of the input buffer to some known value. (same with the phone number)  Strongly suggest inserting: `memset( c, '\0', sizeof( c);` before setting any of the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just write structure to file, and expect it being clean. `fwrite` also, is aimed at binary files, so it would be better for you to use other function (you didn't specify binary write mode in `fopen` call). Way better would be this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[50];
    char phone[11];
}contato;

int main(){
    contato c;
    memset(&c, 0, sizeof(contato));
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("lista_contato.txt", "w");

    printf("Nome: ");
    fgets(c.name, 50, stdin);
    printf("Telefone: ");
    fgets(c.phone, 11, stdin);

    fwrite(c.phone, 1, 11, fp);
    fputc(fp, '\n'); /*To make output readable*/
    fwrite(c.name, 1, 50, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, bruceg was right, you didn't initialize c, and structure contained random data.

Comment: @RafaelRossi No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize c.  In your current code, it will just contain random data.  Add this line before you insert any data into c:

```
memset(&c, 0, sizeof(contato));
```

Comment: Thanks, it got rid of the garbage. But 's a way to deal with the amount of spaces that is printed after my name input ?

Comment: Write null terminator at position where user input ends.

Comment: When you write the entire contents of c to the file, it will include all the null bytes.  If you don't want those in the file, you would have to write each field separately, instead of as one struct.